# UILabel autolayout - stretch horizontal then vertical

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a UILabel. I've set trailing and leading space constraints, also I've added align Y center constraint. I've set Lines count to zero.

[image]

My goal is to stretch UILabel to some maximum width and then add new line. With given constraints I have following result:

[image]

I need first label to be not wider than `P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `prefferedMaxLayoutWidth` in that case. You can read more about this [here](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html).

You should use something like:

```
self.team1Label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 20; // or other value in PT
```